# Can not use expression language functions from Events Trigger body

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using events trigger in ADF v2. My trigger parameter values look like this:-

```
            "parameters": {
                "FolderPath": "@triggerBody().folderPath",
                "FileName": "@triggerBody().fileName",
                "Year": "@{split(@triggerBody().folderPath,'/')[2]}",
                "Month": "@{split(@triggerBody().folderPath,'/')[3]}",
                "Day": "@{split(@triggerBody().folderPath,'/')[4]}",
            }
```

I initially ran it with just 2 initial parameters and the sample values for FolderPath look like this as seen from ADF monitor after a run is succeeded:-

```
test/poc/2019/09/20/00
```

But when I add other parameters to it, like Year, Month, Day as shown here, while publishing the changes, I get an error 'Trigger activation failed':-

[image]

When I hard coded Year, Month, Day in the trigger, it again started working. I am guessing some issues in calling expression language functions from event based trigger. I am basically trying to dynamically calculate individual elements from FolderPath such as 2019 as Year, 09 as Month and so on. How to achieve this?

Comment: Also -- instead of calling @triggerBody for every other parameter, can't I use the value of FolderPath itself and create other parameters , something like calculating additional columns on the basis of 'FolderPath' value

Comment: Try          "Year": "@{split(triggerBody().folderPath,'/')[2]}",
                "Month": "@{split(triggerBody().folderPath,'/')[3]}",
                "Day": "@{split(triggerBody().folderPath,'/')[4]}",

Comment: Basically  delete @ before triggerBody

Comment: yes it works -- but I have another question -- is it really necessary to use triggerBody().folderPath in so many places again and again, since for 'FolderPath' parameter I am already calculating it, can't I use the value of one trigger parameter for calculating other trigger parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting DraganB's comment as an answer here:-

Try

```
"Year": "@{split(triggerBody().folderPath,'/')[2]}", "Month": "@{split(triggerBody().folderPath,'/')[3]}", "Day": "@{split(triggerBody().folderPath,'/')[4]}"
```

Basically delete @ before triggerBody